# Magento 2 - cannot insert block inside another block from the core

Tags: magento-2.1, layout

im trying to insert a custom block inside another block from the core. but for some reasons i cannot do it using referenceBlock. though its working if i use referenceContainer on the 'content', im trying to do it in checkout_cart_index.xml. heres my layout.xml.

```
<body>
    //this one is working
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
               name="sample.name"
               before="-"
               template="My_Module::template.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>

    //this one is not working. 
    //i also tried using renderer.list as reference block name. still not working
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
               name="another.sample.name"
              template="My_Module::template.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>

</body>
```

i have no idea whats wrong since the referenceContainer is working

Answer (score 1):

That is one of the main differences between `container` and `block`.

Container will automatically render it's child blocks whereas block will not.

To render a child inside most blocks you must add `<?= $block->getChildHtml('another.sample.name') ?>` inside the parent blocks template. You need to pass in the `alias` defined on the block, if no alias is set then it will use the `name` attribute.

I say *most blocks* as some blocks will contain `<?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>` which will render all child blocks similar to a container.